# Why are named constructors static

Tags: c++

I was reading a post about [Named Constructors](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/named-ctor-idiom.html). It has declared the named constructors static. What can be the reason for that. Wouldn't a non static method serve the same purpose?

Comment: Nevermind that a non-static constructor is a chicken-and-egg problem, did you even read your article? *Unfortunately the parameters for these two coordinate systems are the same: two floats. This would create an ambiguity error in the overloaded constructors* You might also want to look at the factory pattern.

Comment: @ta.speot.is now I have read the whole article :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A non-static function is associated with an object of a class.

In this case, the whole point of the function is to *create* an object of the class. When you call the function, there *is* no instance of the class with which that function call could be associated.

Answer (score 3):

They have to be `static` methods.

```
class Point {
public:
  static Point rectangular(float x, float y);      // Rectangular coord's
  static Point polar(float radius, float angle);   // Polar coordinates

  ...
private:
  Point();
  Point(float x, float y);     // Rectangular coordinates
  float x_, y_;
};
```

In *Named Constructor Idiom* you should make constructors `private` or `protected`, so you **cannot** have an constructed object in a straight way.

On the other hand, `static` methods don't need to have objects to call, so they don't need constructors too.

Therefore, you can use `static` methods to do something such as returning a constructed object.

Answer (score 1):

Its not a part of some "magic syntax". Its just a **static member** that works as factory for class **Point**. I'll copy example from this link and add explaining comments:

```
#include <cmath>               // To get std::sin() and std::cos()

class Point {
public:
  static Point rectangular(float x, float y);      // Its a static function that returns Point object
  static Point polar(float radius, float angle);   // Its a static function that returns Point object
  // These static methods are the so-called "named constructors"
  ...
private:
  Point(float x, float y);     // Rectangular coordinates
  float x_, y_;
};

inline Point::Point(float x, float y)
  : x_(x), y_(y) { }

inline Point Point::rectangular(float x, float y)
{ return Point(x, y); } //Create new Point object and return it by value

inline Point Point::polar(float radius, float angle)
{ return Point(radius*std::cos(angle), radius*std::sin(angle)); } //Create new Point object and return it by value
```

So, `Point::rectangular` and `Point::polar` is just a factory for class **Point**

Comment: I'm not familiar with this use of the word *fabric*. I don't see the textile analogy. Are you sure that's the right word?

Comment: Fabrication perhaps, e.g factory?

Comment: Yes, it factory, sorry ;)

Answer (score 1):

Well, in a sense it actually can. Named Constructors are effectively the result of merging a factory into the target type. In the original factory pattern, you would have something like this:

```
class PointFactory {
public:
  Point rectangular(float x, float y);      // Rectangular coord's
  Point polar(float radius, float angle);   // Polar coordinates
  // Of course these *could* be static, but they don't *have* to be.
private:
  /* ... */
};
```

If all you want is to create a Point and don't really require a complicated factory type, you can simply move the factory's functionality to the Point type itself. Then you would have to make the then "Named Constructor" member function `static` for the reasons stated in the other answers.